# Securely evaluate simple maths

Tags: php

I would like to know if there was a secure way to evaluate mathematics like

```
2+2
10000+12000
10000-20
2 + 2
40 - 20 + 23 - 12
```

Without having to use `eval()` because the input can come from any users. The things I'd need to implement are only additions and subtractions of whole numbers.

Is there any snippets that already exists for that, or any PHP functions I haven't come across?

Comment: You could sanitize the input first (like using a regex to allow only digits and math operators)

Comment: Are you getting the entire string from user input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would question using `eval`, considering the variety of mathematic functions available in PHP. You've said you only want to do simple math -- the only reason to use `eval` is to perform more complex operations, or to accept the equations whole-cloth from the user.

If you just want to add or subtract, sanitize the input with `intval` and go to town:

```
$number1 = '100';
$number2 = 'shell_exec(\'rm -rf *\')';
echo intval($number1) + intval($number2); // 100
```

Try it: http://codepad.org/LSUDUw1M

This works because `intval` ignores anything non-numeric.

If you are indeed getting the whole equation from user input (ie `100 - 20`), you can use `preg_replace` to remove anything except the allowed operators and numbers:

```
$input = '20 + 4; shell_exec(\'rm *\')';
$input = preg_replace(
    '/[^0-9+-]/', 
    '',
    $input
);
eval('$result = '.$input.';');
echo 'result: '.$result; // 24
```

Try it: http://codepad.org/tnISDPJ3

Here, we're using the regex `/[^0-9+-]/`, which matches anything NOT 0-9 OR + OR - and replaces it with an empty string.

If you want to get more in to depth with allowed equations, taken straight from the `eval` manual page:

```
// credit for code to bohwaz (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#107377)
$test = '2+3*pi';

// Remove whitespaces
$test = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test);

$number = '(?:\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?|pi|π)'; // What is a number
$functions = '(?:abs|a?cosh?|a?sinh?|a?tanh?|exp|log10|deg2rad|rad2deg|sqrt|ceil|floor|round)'; // Allowed PHP functions
$operators = '[+\/*^%-]'; // Allowed math operators
$regexp = '/^(('.$number.'|'.$functions.'\s*\((?1)+\)|\((?1)+\))(?:'.$operators.'(?2))?)+$/'; // Final regexp, heavily using recursive patterns

if (preg_match($regexp, $q))
{
    $test = preg_replace('!pi|π!', 'pi()', $test); // Replace pi with pi function
    eval('$result = '.$test.';');
}
else
{
    $result = false;
}
```

**Documentation**

- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `intval` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
- `eval` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php
- PHP Math functions - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php

Comment: I've tasted the full extent of eval I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the expressions yourself.

Something like this:

```
// Minus is the same as plus a negative
// Also remove spaces after minus signs
$str = preg_replace('/-\s*(\d+)/', '+-$1', $str);

// Split on plusses
$nums = explode('+', $str);

// Trim values
$nums = array_map('trim', $nums);

// Add 'em up
echo array_sum($nums);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/ANc0gh27

Comment: I just hacked it together quickly, glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used this method in calculator script.

```
$field1 = $_GET["field1"];
$field2 = $_GET["field2"];

$answer = $field1 + $field2;
echo "$field1 + $field2 = $answer";
```

Comment: This one doesn't really work actually and doesn't really do what I'd need it to do.

Comment: Oh, But this works fine, But don't know if it doesn't work in your case..Sorry.....

Comment: It's actually adding a value with the same value, basically doing x + x = y.

Comment: Okay, What is feild1 = 10 and feild2 = 15, Obviously in answer they will not be equal?

Comment: @Manhim: That was just an example.  Obviously each `$_GET` should get a different variable.